# Вопрос производительности + БД

Tags: php

Друзья, такой вопрос. Как бы вы поступили и почему ?

Суть вот в чем - есть необходимость записывать в БД ссылки до картинок (до 10шт).

Два варианта событий

```
1 - создать 10 столбцов VARCHAR в базе данных и в них пихать пути до картинок. В PHP обработчике просто перебирать.
2 - создать 1 столбец типа TEXT и записать в них все пути до картинок через запятую, а PHP обработчиком просто разобрать на массив и использовать по своему усмотрению.
```

Что является более правильным ? Или быть может есть что то лучше ?

Где то слышал, что лучше использовать 1 вариант..якобы быстрее отклик по времени исполнения. Так ли это ?

Comment: производительность тут вообще не при чем. А единственно правильным решением будет отдельная таблица.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А лучше нормализовать таблицы.

Таблица data_images: `id, data_id (первичный ключ к data.id), value`
Таблица data: `id, ...`

---

Первый вариант плох тем, что если вдруг придётся ещё 10 картинок добавлять - нужно ручками расширять таблицу (горизонтально будет просто много всего одинакового, что плохо для реляционных бд). А если будет ещё больше?
Второй вариант вполне подходит, если картинок будет реально *немного*. Но в PHP разбивать не всегда удобно и правильно.

Comment: Картинок строго до 10 шт..больше не планируется )

Comment: @steam.apk2 Всё равно предпочтительнее нормализовывать таблицы. Если совсем не хочется заморачиваться - второй. Но первый плохо.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!